# SmsManager em telefones Dual Sim

Tags: java, android, sms

Venho pesquisando sobre o assunto, mas ainda não vi nenhuma solução definitiva para o problema. Bem, minha aplicação faz envio de SMS a partir do SmsManager porém, não pergunta qual chip deve utilizar quando rodada em um aplicativo Dual Sim, simplesmente porque não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Até onde sei, o segundo parâmetro do `smsManager.sendTextMessage` que no momento está declarado como **null** é responsável pelo Centro de Serviço **(SMSC)** que vai ser utilizado para o envio, o que resultaria no envio pelo chip correto, **em partes** já que o usuário pode ter um celular com dois chips da mesma operadora, utilizando assim o mesmo SMSC para os dois chips.

Verifiquei a documentação do SmsManager mas não existe sequer nenhuma informação sobre utilização em aparelhos Dual Sim.

E aqui fica minha dúvida: como realmente utilizar o SmsManager em aparelhos Dual Sim de maneira correta, sendo sempre perguntando qual chip será utilizado para o envio, ou definindo previamente?

Answer (score 0):

Fala Italo,

Eu acredito que essa seja uma função escolhida diretamente no device do usuário.

É possível definir qual SIM será o padrão de ligações e envio de SMS, para revogar essa permissão, no próprio device deve-se fazer:

```
Configurações >> Wireless & Networks >> SIM Management >> Padrão 

Settings >> Messages >> e selecionar 'Perguntar sempre'.
```

Com isso toda vez que for mandar um SMS através de um APP, será perguntado qual SIM deve ser usado.

Via código não tem como desativar a escolha padrão do usuário.

Abraços.